# Testing an Encoder's Accuracy

Tags: encoder, rs422

I'm using a high-frequency (1024PPR) RS-422 encoder, connected to a differential line receiver, and in turn, a quadrature encoder interface.

Initial tests were conducted with a low-PPR hand turned knob, where I could visually verify that the pulses were being counted correctly.

With a high-frequency encoder, how would I go about determining whether the counts are accurate? I should point out that the QEI is guaranteed to work at extremely high frequencies, so really what I want to be checking is whether the RS-422 receiver is correctly interpreting/outputting pulses, etc.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is there an Index output to verify the up/down counts return to zero accurately?

Comment: Seems to me like you should be more worried about the QEI, and a 2-channel function generator would suffice to test that.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, why should I be more worried about the QEI?

Comment: The QEI will be high speed logic above the RS-422 implementation and resulting MHz-km product maximum and RPM* 1024 ppr frequency. What are your specs?

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist, I'm using the LPC1768 QEI. LPC1768 pins accept TTL voltage levels, and the output from the RS-422 receiver is TTL compatible. I'm not sure of the maximum frequency, but I've heard it's upwards of 50,000hz.

Comment: Because there could be firmware or peripheral hardware issues, eg. with the index pulse reset (if used) or with rollover (if no index pulse). RS422 drivers/receivers should just work provided the cables are reasonably well terminated.

Comment: Your specs shud be RPM max/60*1024

Comment: The point is Is message rate in 422 line, let's say is 100Hz or 10ms. What is the QEI pulse out going to be if in 10ms encoder position changes more than one? In other words how you manage two subsequent messages with position change above one?

Answer (score 2):

Initialize a software counter to 0 when Index is detected once.

Use the Z index signal as a "parity or null count check" for up/down counts in any direction or speed and when Index is detected the count should be = zero.

If a fault is detected, then determine the error value and cause of error by direction or speed or noise interference.

### Test Engineer advice

- define acceptable immunity specs. , conducted, radiated and encoder speed, temperature, humidity, vibration, shock etc.
- Test to (non-destructive) failure levels of signal integrity to verify your SNR margin.  e.g. Impulse current generator on cables nearby or brushed motor under load., ESD tests. etc
- since signal integrity is statistical there may be a probability of error which depends on SNR and margin.
  [image]

Comment: So, essentially, I'm checking that when the index count changes, the encoder count is index count * 1024?